# ¿Cómo agregar mi gson en mi llamado de método?

Tags: java, android, get

usé https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ para mi gson

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá cuándo abro "rowset"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me creó 3 clases "Datareq" "_03011aDatareq" y "Rowset"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la primera con esto

```
public class Datareq {

@SerializedName("03_011A_DATAREQ")
@Expose
private com.example.getquantum._03011aDatareq _03011aDatareq;

public com.example.getquantum._03011aDatareq get03011aDatareq() {
    return _03011aDatareq;
}

public void set03011aDatareq(com.example.getquantum._03011aDatareq _03011aDatareq) {
    this._03011aDatareq = _03011aDatareq;
}
```

}

la segunda

```
public class _03011aDatareq {

@SerializedName("tableId")
@Expose
private String tableId;
@SerializedName("rowset")
@Expose
private List<Rowset> rowset = null;
@SerializedName("records")
@Expose
private Integer records;
@SerializedName("moreRecords")
@Expose
private Boolean moreRecords;

public String getTableId() {
    return tableId;
}

public void setTableId(String tableId) {
    this.tableId = tableId;
}

public List<Rowset> getRowset() {
    return rowset;
}

public void setRowset(List<Rowset> rowset) {
    this.rowset = rowset;
}

public Integer getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(Integer records) {
    this.records = records;
}

public Boolean getMoreRecords() {
    return moreRecords;
}

public void setMoreRecords(Boolean moreRecords) {
    this.moreRecords = moreRecords;
}
```

}

y la tercera

```
public class Rowset {

@SerializedName("NRO_INTERNO")
@Expose
private String nroInterno;
@SerializedName("TIPO_INTERNO")
@Expose
private String tipoInterno;
@SerializedName("FECHA_FACTURA")
@Expose
private String fechaFactura;
@SerializedName("MONTO")
@Expose
private Integer monto;
@SerializedName("FECHA_VENCIMIENTO")
@Expose
private String fechaVencimiento;
@SerializedName("NRO_LEGAL")
@Expose
private String nroLegal;

public String getNroInterno() {
    return nroInterno;
}

public void setNroInterno(String nroInterno) {
    this.nroInterno = nroInterno;
}

public String getTipoInterno() {
    return tipoInterno;
}

public void setTipoInterno(String tipoInterno) {
    this.tipoInterno = tipoInterno;
}

public String getFechaFactura() {
    return fechaFactura;
}

public void setFechaFactura(String fechaFactura) {
    this.fechaFactura = fechaFactura;
}

public Integer getMonto() {
    return monto;
}

public void setMonto(Integer monto) {
    this.monto = monto;
}

public String getFechaVencimiento() {
    return fechaVencimiento;
}

public void setFechaVencimiento(String fechaVencimiento) {
    this.fechaVencimiento = fechaVencimiento;
}

public String getNroLegal() {
    return nroLegal;
}

public void setNroLegal(String nroLegal) {
    this.nroLegal = nroLegal;
}
```

}

usé una interface para poder conectarme con los headers ( me saltó código 200)

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {




@GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH")


Call<Datareq>getDatareqs(@Query("Cliente")double cliente,@Header("Authorization")String authHeader,
                                @Header("Cookie") String cookie,
                                @Header ("Content-Type") String content);}
```

y finalmente mi mainActivity. dónde quiero plasmar mi gson en un textview con scroll

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
   private TextView textViewResult;

   Rowset reqRowset;


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Resul);

           Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl("http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/")
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                   .build();




           JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

           String userName ="sbasilico";
           String password ="xxxxxx";
           String base = userName + ":" + password;



                   String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

           Call<_03011aDatareq> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs(80003, authHeader,"JSESSIONID=fYAV2KfouyICoHiKGuJ5n_-Q0kQOc-KNl6HmFk9Ce8K5JQtuMa7A!-530853743", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

           call.enqueue(new Callback<_03011aDatareq>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call<_03011aDatareq> call, Response<_03011aDatareq> response) {

                   if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                       _03011aDatareq datareq = response.body();

                       List<Rowset> rowset = datareq.getRowset();
                       for(Rowset d : rowset){
                           { reqRowset = d;

                               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void run() {
                                       textViewResult.setText("code: "+ response.code()+ "\n");
                                       textViewResult.setText(reqRowset.getNroInterno()+ "\n") ;
                                       textViewResult.setText( reqRowset.getTipoInterno() + "\n");
                                       textViewResult.setText( reqRowset.getMonto() + "\n");
                                       textViewResult.setText( reqRowset.getFechaVencimiento() + "\n");
                                       textViewResult.setText( reqRowset.getNroLegal() + "\n");



                                   }
                               });

                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<_03011aDatareq> call, Throwable t) {
                   textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());

               }


           });
       }
   }
```

Antes tenia problemas con los certificados, pero ya no. ahora la cuestión es que no estoy logrando que aparezca. quizas ayuda el error  que me aparece en el debug. tampoco logro conectarenn código lo de  la subclase "Rowset"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿el valor `03_011A_DATAREQ` está en todas las respuestas de tu API o ese es un valor aleatorio?

Comment: me lo agregó el  jsonchema. es el objeto que contiene mis jsons. aparece cuando consulto en el postman

Comment: Lo pregunto porque si ese valor cambia tendrás problemas más adelante si haces funcionar el código, porque estás modelando las clases en base a `03_011A_DATAREQ`. Así que **debes estar totalmente seguro de que ese valor no cambiará nunca en las respuestas**. Por otra parte, en visto que agregó un guión bajo al nombre de la clase, no sé si eso dará problema con los *getter*  y *setter* por ejemplo ¿? Sea como sea, ¿qué depuraciones del código haz hecho y con qué resultados? Por ejemplo, ¿el código entra en el `onResponse`?

Comment: es cómo que llega a leer los certificados 

((Retrofit)this.this$0).shadow$_klass_ = No such instance field: 'this$0'
this = {MainActivity@4140} 
savedInstanceState = null
retrofit = {Retrofit@4141} 
jsonPlaceHolderApi = {$Proxy0@4142} "retrofit2.Retrofit$1@2e60a340"
userName = "sbasilico"
password = "sxxxxxx"
base = "xxxxxx"

pero despues de eso no sigue, tenes razon no llega a leer mi response

Comment: subo el error que me saltó en la publiacion

Comment: Se agradece que pongas en las preguntas con el texto, no la imagen, de la traza completa del error. Si te da error de Cast comenta temporalmente toda la parte donde haces casting del objeto y muestra un Log de la respuesta para revisarla:  `Log.d( "AAA",response.body() );`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127344/discussion-between-giuliano-capovilla-and-a-cedano).